# What is the best way to return most recent posts from Fauna DB for a blog, etc

Tags: faunadb

I am building a simple custom headless CMS with React to save data in Fauna via API Gateway and Lambda. To list my posts in the admin, I would like to get the data from my collection sorted by a date value.

When I create a new index to do this, I expected to get the same data/structure that is in the default index that is created. However, what I've found is that it returns only the data explicitly defined in the index without any keys to describe what values are present.

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602964/how-do-i-create-an-index-in-fauna-db-that-returns-sorted-data-in-key-value-pairs) without the context before and got a great response, but I would like to know more generally what the best and most performant practice would be to accomplish this in Fauna.  I have not discovered a way to sort data outside of creating an index.

This default behavior is counter intuitive to me.  It seems there would be a simpler way to return the data in reversed order. I would love to know why this is the default behavior. I'm sure there are good reasons for it rationalized by folks who are much smarter than I am. Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Also, interesting, what you are building. Will it be open-source? I'd be interested in seeing your approach :)

Comment: I hadn't really even thought about open sourcing it.  That's not a bad idea at all.  I got so frustrated jumping through hoops wiith other CMSs that I decided to roll my own. The front end will be a decoupled Gatsby site, so I just started with Gatsby for this project though there's really nothing to build. When I get it to a decent place, I'll let you know.  Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is indeed a very good reason for this. In contrast to many other databases, FaunaDB took the decisions not to **allow** you to do inefficient things in order to save you from unpleasant surprises. When you sort data in a database, it either uses an index typically one of two things happens:

- There is an index defined because you knew you were going to do that, you care about performance and you thought about it. The index is used for the sort.
- You forgot about the index, or your data is so small that you didn't care, the query engine is going to still do this yet is going to do this in a horribly inefficient way.

If you end up in the second case where you forgot and you do this on massive data, then you might have a performance problem, if that database is auto-scaling and pay-as-you-go than ok.. no problem.. the database should be be able to handle but since it's pay-as-you-go, it'll be expensive.

The same counts for sorting. Maybe a database has a clever way to reverse a sort order but it might just as well not use the index and do something super inefficient by running over that complete dataset until to the end and start reading in reverse order.

To avoid nasty pricing surprises, most things that you can do that requires an index to do efficiently will not be possible without defining that index in advance.

Is that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: That really helps me understand.  I've been thinking about things from the perspective of my small project and larger datasets reveal the need for this.  If I've provided enough detail to speculate on my project, would you recommend one of the two options you provided in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602964/how-do-i-create-an-index-in-fauna-db-that-returns-sorted-data-in-key-value-pairs), or would there be another best practice?  Thanks!

Comment: I always recommend:
- start with the Map/Get approach, it's way more flexible but you will incur much more reads. However, your data model is going to still change in the beginning and I assume you won't have that much data to start with so you'll probably even still be under the free-tier for a while.

- If you feel like your data model is quite stable and there is a frequent call you want to optimise, make a dedicated index with all values you need and move to the second approach only at that point. Before that is probably premature optimisation.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks so much for all your help.