# Fauna CreateIndex and sort using with the GraphQL endpoint

Tags: graphql, faunadb

I am using FaunaDB to prototype a web app and I have some datas already inserted into an index `all_facts`. Now I want to sort the facts by a number, no problem following the tutorial on faunadb docs.

But the problem is that the new index `facts_sorted` is an **array of array instead an array of objects** like all others indexes. How is supposed to use a created custom index within the graphql endpoint?

Already saw [How do I create an index in Fauna DB that returns sorted data in key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602964/how-do-i-create-an-index-in-fauna-db-that-returns-sorted-data-in-key-value-pairs) but it's not helpful and not speaking at all about the problem with GraphQL endpoint.

Comment: I can understand that the previous question is not helpful specifically to you but you will have to provide us with more details to be able to help you. Ideally, show us the GraphQL schema you have. How are you trying to use the index, via a User Defined Function, if so, show us the UDF you have created so far? Be complete else it will be impossible for us to determine what you are trying to do and help you :)